# Why does the Web Bluetooth Pairing Screen Show Multiple Entries for the Same Device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

When my web application goes to pair with my device, I get multiple entries for the same device on the pairing screen.

Any ideas why?

[image: D]

Comment: How can Stackoverflow  allow a post to be down graded without explanation?

Comment: It has been more than a year since this article was written:  https://medium.com/@jayhanlon/welcome-wagon-dd57cbdd54d9  Where is the change???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Reilly Grant, who is working on the Web Bluetooth specification, this issue is a bug in Chromium.
https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/462